# Not using a form to send form data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, form-submit, spam-prevention

To prevent spam I'm thinking of removing `<form>`and send the data from the input fields with AJAX instead.

**On the PHP side I will probably use this to make it safer:**

`$clean = strip_tags($html, '<p><br>');`

Any pitfalls?

Comment: Did you test it already?

Comment: No, but I know I can get the data with JS from the input fields and then send it to PHP with Ajax.

I just don't know if there are any downsides I have not thought of, perhaps security or usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself I use ajax instead sometimes, the downside for me is that with ajax I have not been able to send files (e.g. images) at least without Jquery.

So, if you don't need to send files it is ok or at least I do so sometimes, although the reason you say: the spam, I don't get it

Comment: Bots search the web to fill in forms. If there is no form, nothing to fill in, and nothing to send.

Comment: You can use [FormData](http://www.webcodegeeks.com/html5/html5-file-upload-example/) in javascript if the browser is compliant to send files over ajax

Comment: Then I believe you Darkbee because last time I checked that stuff they (browser docs) say the formData was experimental code for sending files.